# reading data from file and breaking it into tokens

Tags: java, token, stringtokenizer

I am using the following code after reading from a text file as to break the input of the text file into tokens:

```
String input;
while(true)
{
    input = bin.readLine(); 
    if (input == null) 
    {
        System.out.println( "No data found in the file");
        return 0;
    }
    break;
}

StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input);
```

Then:

```
for (int i=0; i < numAtt; i++) 
{
    attributeN[i]  = tokenizer.nextToken();
}
```

I cannot understand why the attributeNames gets the tokens in the first line of the text file only, doesn't while(true) keep on reading the whole file? Also is there a way to avoid the while(true) and using break to terminate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `break` after `if (input == null) { }` is breaking the while, so your code only read one line.

> Also is there a way to avoid the while(true) and using break to
>   terminate it?

Do it in this way:

```
while ((input = bin.readLine()) != null) {
    //split input line here 
}
```

Also, consider using [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split the line in tokens. Example for the separator `,` :

```
String attributeNames[] = input.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using:

```
 String splittedString[] = input.split("the separator");
```

It's recommended by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to get tokens from the first line? If so, you don't need the `while` loop at all. Just remove the `while {` from the beginning and `break; }` from the end.